# Integrating other user's personal Google calendar into site

Tags: html, google-calendar-api, embed

For my website which advertises local events at my university with a particular emphasis on accessibility and being outdoors given the world situation, I have embedded my account's calendar so that users can see our events and save them etc. The goal I am trying to accomplish is to integrate users personal calendar into the website so that when they log in they can see their own calendar.

Google log in is integrated and functional on the site, however I cannot find any info about how to embed a user's personal calendar as all the info google provides on the topic is how to embed the site admin's calendar. The most simple and barebones way to do this would be an iframe which i've tried however it is protected by google from displaying.

Has anyone attempted anything similar or had any success with this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate someone else's calendar you can **embed** it, using the instructions in this [link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en&ref_topic=3417970). However, for this option, you will need to have access to each user's calendar, meaning, they will have to have shared it with you.

Another option is to retrieve all the events from the users calendars and integrate them in your website. For this, you could benefit from using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).

#### Reference

- [Add a Google Calendar to your website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en&ref_topic=3417970);
- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).